Positivity of the bidual operator

How is the fixed space of a bounded linear operator related to the fixed space of the bidual operator?

Motivation of question: I have a strongly continuous semigroup $(T(t))_{t\ge 0}$ on a Banach lattice $E$ and a bounded operator $R$ on $E$ that is positive on the fixed space
$$\{x \in E: T(t)x=x \text{ for all }t\ge 0\}$$
and I'm trying to show that the (Banach space) bidual $R''$  is positive on the fixed space
$$\{x \in E'': T(t)''x=x \text{ for all }t\ge 0\}.$$

Honestly, I think your question is missing context and not on point. The fixed space coincides with $\ker A$ and thus, $R(\lambda, A) x = \frac 1 \lambda x$ for all fixed vectors $x$. So, the assertion is equivalent to $\lambda >0$, which does not give you any information at all in the context of semigroup theory.

@Yaddle You're right. My situation is indeed more complicated and in trying to simplify, I made it trivial. I've edited my question.

I’m not sure much more can be said than just saying the fixed point space of the double dual operator contains the weak$^\ast$ closure of the fixed point space of the original operator. It certainly can contain the latter space strictly - for example the left shift operator on $\ell^1$ has no fixed point (apart from $0$), but on $(\ell^1)^{\ast\ast}$ the bidual operator does have nontrivial fixed points, for example the Banach limit.

In fact, here is a counterexample in the same spirit as my comment:
Let $E = L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with its usual Banach lattice structure. $(T(t))_{t \geq 0}$ be the strongly continuous semigroup given by translations. Then the fixed point space $\{x \in E: T(t)x = x \; \forall t\} = \{0\}$, so any $R$ is positive on the fixed point space. However, because $\mathbb{R}$ is amenable, there exists a nontrivial positive $\varphi \in E’’ = L^\infty(\mathbb{R})’$ that is invariant under translations, i.e., invariant under $T(t)’’$ for all $t$. Just choosing any $R$ whose double dual sends $\varphi$ to an element that’s not positive gives a counterexample. (For example, $R = -T(1)$.)
